# Customizing ListBoxItem: Getting rid of border + clickable area

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, border, listboxitem

I'm customizing a `ListBoxItem`, and I'm struggling with a couple of issues.

- The `ItemTemplate` is a `StackPanel` of vertical orientation, whose height is set to 120px.  But only clicking the label or the image causes the `ListBox` to select the item, not the open area below the label.  How do I get the open area to also cause a change in selection?  I'm considering adding a styled `Button` as `ListBoxItem`, but I wonder if it can be done any easier.
- There's a 1px line between the `ListBox` container and the `ListBoxItem`'s that I'm not able to get rid of.  How do I get rid of it?  Here's a screenshot:

[image]

XAML:

```
<ListBox Grid.Row="1" ItemsSource="{Binding MenuButtonInfoList}"
        SelectedIndex="{Binding SelectedMainMenuIndex, Mode=TwoWay}">
    <ListBox.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListBox}">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="Transparent" />
            <Setter Property="Width" Value="160px" />
            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{StaticResource PrimaryColor}" />
            <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="0, 1, 0, 0" />
        </Style>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}">
            <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="True" />
            <Setter Property="SnapsToDevicePixels" Value="True" />
            <Setter Property="Template">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ListBoxItem}">
                        <Border x:Name="MenuButtonBorder" SnapsToDevicePixels="True"
                                BorderBrush="{StaticResource PrimaryColor}" BorderThickness="0, 0, 0, 1">
                            <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" Height="120px">
                                <Image Source="{Binding ImageFilePath}" Height="30" Width="30" />
                                <Label x:Name="MenuButtonLabel" Content="{Binding Label}" 
                                        FontSize="{StaticResource Title1FontSize}"
                                        Foreground="{StaticResource PrimaryColor}" />
                            </StackPanel>
                        </Border>
                        <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                            <Trigger Property="IsFocused" Value="True">
                                <Setter TargetName="MenuButtonBorder" Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource PrimaryColor}" />
                                <Setter TargetName="MenuButtonLabel" Property="Foreground" Value="{StaticResource HighlightColor}" />
                            </Trigger>
                        </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </ListBox.Resources>
</ListBox>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How do I get the open area to also cause a change in selection?

Set `Background="Transparent"` on the `StackPanel` in your item template.  That will make the entire panel hit testable.

> There's a 1px line between the ListBox container and the ListBoxItem's that I'm not able to get rid of. How do I get rid of it?

Override the `ListBox` template to remove the 1px padding:

```xml
<ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ListBox}">
  <Border Name="Bd"
          Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
          BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
          BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"
          SnapsToDevicePixels="true">
     <!-- Padding="1" (removed) -->
    <ScrollViewer Padding="{TemplateBinding Padding}"
                  Focusable="false">
      <ItemsPresenter SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}"/>
    </ScrollViewer>
  </Border>
  <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
    <Trigger Property="IsEnabled"
              Value="false">
      <Setter TargetName="Bd"
              Property="Background"
              Value="{DynamicResource {x:Static SystemColors.ControlBrushKey}}"/>
    </Trigger>
    <MultiTrigger>
      <MultiTrigger.Conditions>
        <Condition Property="IsGrouping" Value="true" />
        <Condition Property="VirtualizingPanel.IsVirtualizingWhenGrouping" Value="false" />
      </MultiTrigger.Conditions>
      <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll" Value="false"/>
    </MultiTrigger>
  </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
</ControlTemplate>
```

Place the above in a `Setter` for the `Template` property in your `ListBox` style.

Comment: It worked superbly!  Thanks a million. :-)  Why does it work to set the background to transparent, by the way?  Is it that the area's content goes from "nothing" (i.e. nothing that triggers events) to "something", even though that something is transparent?

Comment: Yes, that's exactly right.  `Transparent` creates a transparent surface.  While you can't see it, it's there for hit testing purposes.  A `null` brush creates no surface at all, so there's nothing to hit test against.  It's a useful thing to remember when working with WPF.